# Как получить из файла .css список классов

Tags: css, node.js, файлы

У меня есть файл .css в облаке где лежат классы.
Как получить из файла по ссылке его классы в массив?

Answer (score -1):

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="link/to/cloud/styles.css">
</head>
```

И, по идее, всё. Должно всё подхватиться.

Comment: простите, не учел одного, я делаю это на nodejs

Comment: А что за массив должен получиться? Только с названиями классов? Или с содержимым? Не очень понятна цель.

Comment: Может это будет полезно? [css-parser](https://github.com/reworkcss/css)